# cisco switch enable port pysnmp

Tags: cisco, pysnmp

trying to convert this line in to pysnmp

snmpset -v 2c -On -r 5 -t 2 -c private ip-address .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.369098771 i 1

I am trying to take a working walk function and modify it but my knowledge with SNMP makes it very hard to understand pysnmp doc

this is just part of the code

from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

```
        device_target = (self.ip, self.port)
        res = None
        # Create a PYSNMP cmdgen object
        cmd_gen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
        (error_detected, error_status, error_index, snmp_data) = cmd_gen.setCmd(
            cmdgen.CommunityData(community_string),
            cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(device_target), '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.369098771', 1
            lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True)
```

I know I am missing something, can any one help please

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend upgrading your pysnmp to the latest released version and use "hlapi" interface.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

device_target = (self.ip, self.port)
community_string = 'private'

cmd_gen = setCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                 CommunityData(community_string),
                 UdpTransportTarget(device_target, timeout=2.0, retries=5),
                 ContextData(),
                 ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.369098771'), Integer32(1)),
                 lookupMib=False
)

res = None  # True denotes a failure

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(cmd_gen)

if errorIndication:
    res = errorIndication
elif errorStatus:
    res = '%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?')

if res:
    print('SNMP failed: %s' % res)
```

References: [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/modifying-variables.html#set-scalars-values)